# Drop Create table vs Truncate table in Mysql

Tags: mysql

In a daily cron job, I need to create a table in Mysql, do some processing and at the end drop it (no longer need this table).

My question is which of the below two strategies is better in terms of CPU utilization and memory footprint:

1. CREATE table at the start of the job and DROP it at the end.
2. TRUNCATE table at the end of the job (i.e. table is never dropped, just that it is truncated after every job run).

In the 1st approach, a new table has to be created in every job run, whereas in the 2nd approach, table remains in Mysql 24*7 even though it is not needed after the job run.

Comment: Well an empty table won't hurt performance, as reading it would take such a minimal time it's not even worth considering it as an overhead. I prefer option 2 - just add data and truncate at end of day :)

Comment: Advantage of create/drop is that you don't care if the table structure changes as it's always created with whatever structure is currently required.  Truncate is good, but also needs to maintain the table.

Answer (score 2):

you can create temporary table instead of creating actual table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 AS (SELECT * FROM table1)
```

Comment: Can't use temp table because i am using a MysqlConnectionPool and for executing individual statements I can get different connections

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning use this query

```
Select * into test from Table
```

And at the last truncate it and drop it.

```
Truncate table test
Or
Drop table test
```